MIssing beacons for realtek wifi using airodump-ng
So i installed https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au on my new ubuntu system. Using a realtek RTL8812AU USB wireless .
Installed without problems but running airodump-ng getting no beacons at all.
Wireless is in monitor mode.
Any advice would be helpfull.
